# Fail to pass a List with a lot of Itens between Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, transactions, android-binder

I have this code:

`Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, nextActivity);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(nameParameter, serializable);`

My serializable is a ArrayList with a bunch of elements.
When I use the method startActivity.
A FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION happens. 
How I can solve this?

Comment: The title of your problem suggests it only does this with large number of items, so is it fair to say it is not a problem with 1 item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an intent has a limited max size. consider passing your data in some other way: either as a list of IDs, in a file, in a database...

Comment: Yes, the problem doesn't happen when I have just 1 item in my List.